# Your Ruby version is 2.2.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

It is confusing to me that I have in my gemfile this code,

```
ruby "2.1.2"
```

But the terminal keeps printing ruby 'Your Ruby version is 2.2.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2'. I don't get it, what am I missing ? Attached below what I see in the output

[image]
[image]

Comment: set your RVM again to 2.1.2 and reopen your terminal. It may help you

Comment: Switch to ruby `2.1.2` and it will work.  It's specifying a specific version of ruby to run the app against, presumably because it's been tested against that.  If you have a full suite of tests, switch the ruby version to 2.2.2 and run the tests, upgrading the app.

Comment: I had same problem when I had a  file '.ruby-version' in application folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your terminal then:

```
ruby -v
rvm use 2.1.2
```

if didnt work, check this RVM link: [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/basics)

Comment: it does work, but the configuration is not saved. everytime i open a new tab, i've to execute `rvm use 2.2.3`. Even setting it as default using `rvm --default use 2.2.3` doesn't work

Comment: check your ruby versions: `rvm list`

Comment: FYI.. https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3630#issuecomment-193742781 , 
https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/2519#issuecomment-193742682